# Question if I have a dedicated or integrated graphics card and what is the difference?

Tags: graphics-cards, memory

as the title says. I just want to ask if I have a dedicated or integrated graphics card and what is the difference? And also, what are your suggestions on:

Should I upgrade my RAM? or Should I upgrade my graphics card? Thank you!

```
Operating System: Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit (6.3, Build 9600) (9600.winblue_ltsb.150715-0840)

Language: English (Regional Setting: English)


System Manufacturer: System manufacturer
   System Model: System Product Name
           BIOS: BIOS Date: 01/21/15 14:14:16 Ver: 07.02
      Processor: AMD A8-6600K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics    (4 CPUs), ~3.9GHz
         Memory: 4096MB RAM
Available OS Memory: 3016MB RAM
      Page File: 1392MB used, 4695MB available
    Windows Dir: C:\Windows
DirectX Version: DirectX 11
DX Setup Parameters: Not found
User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
System DPI Setting: 96 DPI (100 percent)
DWM DPI Scaling: Disabled
 DxDiag Version: 6.03.9600.17415 64bit Unicode


 Card name: AMD Radeon HD 8570D
   Manufacturer: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
      Chip type: AMD Radeon HD 8570D (0x990E)
       DAC type: Internal DAC(400MHz)
    Device Type: Full Device
     Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_990E&SUBSYS_85261043&REV_00
 Display Memory: 2294 MB
 Dedicated Memory: 1014 MB
  Shared Memory: 1280 MB
   Current Mode: 1024 x 768 (32 bit) (60Hz)
   Monitor Name: Generic PnP Monitor
  Monitor Model: L1553S
     Monitor Id: GSM3BB0
    Native Mode: 1024 x 768(p) (60.004Hz)
    Output Type: HD15
```

Comment: Your question has been put on hold because you're asking too many different things that will result in a wide spectrum of answers. Please see our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/206/155) for ways to improve your question so it can be reopened. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have an dedicated graphic card as well as an integrated. You have an AMD A series processor which has an iGPU, you should definitely chech if your cards arde compatible and if they support CrossFireX in order to get the most out of your system. As far as your RAM is ckncerned, yes you should definitely upgrade your memory to at least 8GB since you have a 64-bit processor in order for your pc to handle multitasking smoother... Your dedicated graphics card is pretty outdated as well, in fact i think your integrated may offer better oerformance (I haven't done any reserach on that it's just a feeling, you should check out if that's the case though, and if you can't run them in CrossFire, at least make sure you are using whichever one is better).

Comment: Hello, @Rayond Ogunjimi! Thank you for your respond on my question. But please can you tell me more on what's the difference between integrated and dedicated? Just a simple one. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, sorry that I didn't include that in my original answer. The difference between a dedicated and an integrated graphic card is that an integrated card is integrated into the processor so, basically not only does the orocessor act as the brain of your computer and do calculations to run applications but it also makes calculations for you to be able to display graphical elements. The problem with these is that they are often the worst of both worlds, not as good of a processor neither of a graphics card, they also produce more heat. On laptops this is a very popular solution.

Comment: I see. I guess I will just have to upgrade my ram! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that would be a good idea.